# Laptop locks up when unplugging ac, plus weirdness

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, nvidia-prime

The laptop in question is an MSI GS43VR-6RE, with a Skylake CPU and nVidia 1060. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1. Its not a hardware issue because it works fine in (bleh) Windows. I'm using the nVidia-375 drivers from the PPA. Using `nvidia-prime` for the switchable graphics.

Laptop locks up completely -- cannot switch to a console or interact with the system in any way once it's locked up. Logs never show anything, the system seems to freeze up before anything useful can get written.

However! *It only does this when I'm using the intel graphics* -- using the nVidia graphics everything works perfectly. But then battery life is pretty lousy so it's not a great solution to just keep it on nVidia all the time (also the fans kick in a lot louder).

It locks up when the ac is unplugged and plugging it back in doesn't fix it, the power button needs to be held down to get control back. It also crashes is when I switch graphics with `sudo prime-select intel` and logout, it'll lock up in the exact same fashion. It also locks up on shutdown some way. So the Intel graphics are totally unusable although they appear to display fine. None of this happens on nVidia.

I've tried..

- Changing to a 4.8 kernel
- Upgrading the intel drivers
- All the 4.4 kernel stuff from here (firmware, 20-intel.conf) https://github.com/linuxenko/ubuntu-skylake-i915-video-fix
- Updating the BIOS
- Threatening it with violence (it knows its too expensive to smash)

And so far nothing has worked.

Here is something weird: After updating the BIOS, it toggled secure boot back on. Before I noticed that, I booted up -- it wouldn't load the nVidia drivers at all so it was running on intel graphics... but it didn't hang up in any of the above cases anymore! When I turned secure boot back off, it loads up the nvidia fine but on intel graphics the problems return. So I'm not sure what that means, but it's interesting and suggests *something*, but I don't know what.

Comment: Test with nvidia-367 too, no changes.

Answer (score 6):

OP solved their own problem (edited out of the question):

> I added to the kernel boot parameters `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows
>   2009'` and the issue magically went away

This is done by editing the configuration file for GRUB:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find the line that starts

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

and add the parameters you need to those already between the quotes, so you have, for example

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'"
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```